# i wanted to add a tooltip in my cakephp project for the text fields

Tags: cakephp

I wanted to add a tooltip in my cakephp project for the text fields.so the whenever user start entering the value in the text fields a tooltip should open and guide him the required values for the field. So that user will not get confused what to enter. (it might be jquery or javascript)

Answer (score 0):

With jQueryUI it's quite simple to achieve. Just use the [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) function on your input fields to have the "possible values" be displayed.

Just add a script block to your page with the possible values and attach it. Like:

```
$this->Html->scriptBlock(
<<<JS
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ];
  $( "#ModelField" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
JS
);
```

Followed by your form code.